# Structure of tables for storing shops/feedbacks

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

I'm going to make some web applicatiob using Rails/PostgreSQL, and I need your advice about a piece of database structure. There are 2 tables: shops and feebacks. "Shops" must store some basic info: name, address, etc. "Feedbacks" must store info about feedback: description, user's rating for store. 
The web app must show shops and their average ratings. I can store all info about ratings in "feedbacks" table and calculate average values using SQL functions (get all feedbacks by shop_id, sum it and divide to number of feedbacks). But may be it is good to have 2 additional fields "rating", "count_of_feedbacks" in "shops" table in order to do it faster? Please, give me advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing, you are describing (creating additional fields "to do it faster") before even knowing if it will be slow is called premature optimization. Ant is a bad thing. A very, very bad thing.

Also you want to duplicate data in your db - that is a bad thing too. You will have to maintain correct version of `rating` for every update - that is not so easy to do with multiple concurrent transactions/connections.

My advise - keep it simple and only fix performance problems when they become real. There are plenty ways to fix them in modern databases.